# How can I access the "certificate enrollment requests" store in C#?

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

How do I access via C# the keys stored in the Certificate Enrollment Requests store?

[image: Certificate Enrollment Requests]

I tried using:

```
var requestCertStore = new X509Store("Certificate Enrollment Requests", 
                                     StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
requestCertStore.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
var certs = requestCertStore.Certificates;
```

but the `certs` collection does not contain the certificate I'm looking to access in the "Certificate Enrollment Requests" store. I also don't see any [`StoreName` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx) that corresponds to this store, so using the `new X509Store(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation)` constructor isn't an option.

Is it not possible to retrieve these certs via C#/.NET?

Comment: You say you _can't_ use the constructor which takes a name and location, but why not? `StoreName` would be `"Certificate Enrollment Requests"` and `StoreLocation` equal to `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`.

Comment: @Mr. Disapppoint, StoreName is an enum, not a string. I tried it using the string constructor as well, no luck. See above.

Comment: @Mike Atlas: Are you accessing the store as an admin?  Just a hunch...

Comment: @Jonny, yeah, definitely as an admin. I have no problem accessing the other normal cert stores and manipulating them.

Comment: @Mike: To be honest, after digging a little, I don't think working with the CER is part of the .NET API. You may be able to work with it at a lower level through use of Windows or Server libraries. I've done a lot of work with X509 but never had to work with actual requests.

Comment: @Jonny, check out my answer, I figured it out! :) It is possible.

Comment: Ya, don't mind me - I have these odd bouts of being idiotic.

Comment: @Mike: Leave it to microsoft to call it something different than it is. Thanks for sharing this tid bit.

Comment: @Jonny, I assume if it were in the enum, that would be the value (`StoreName.REQUEST`), right? Thanks for the upvote if it was you that provided.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah that's what I would assume as well. Why they couldn't do 'StoreName.REQUEST' in the first place, no one will ever know. It sure would have made things easier for you. Yeah I gave you the +1. I currently still work with WSE 3.0 and any x509 info I can gain is always a plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use `"REQUEST"` instead of `"Certificate Enrollment Requests"`:

```
var requestCertStore = new X509Store("REQUEST", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
requestCertStore.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
var certs = requestCertStore.Certificates;
```

I found the hint here: [Delete a pending certificate request](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5bb38c96-344d-44d9-9b2c-a82909fca4ec/).